# Validation at type level

Tags: validation, haskell, type-families

Say I would like to construct subtypes satisfying certain invariants without help of external tools such as LiquidHaskell (ideally I want to do this even without typeclasses). What is the most elegant way to do it? So far I tried the following:

```
class Validated a where
  type Underlying a
  validate :: Underlying a -> Bool
  construct :: Underlying a -> a
  use :: a -> Underlying a

makeValidated :: Validated a => Underlying a -> Maybe a
makeValidated u = if validate u 
                    then Just (construct u)
                    else Nothing


newtype Name = Name String
instance Validated Name where
  type Underlying Name = String
  validate str = and  [ isUppercase (str !! 0 )
                      , all isLetter str ]
  construct = Name
  use (Name str) = str
```

I assume that if I don't export the "Name" constructor from the module, I will have a working solution, because the only way to construct an element of the type would be through makeValidated function.

However compiler complains as such:

```
Could not deduce (Underlying a0 ~ Underlying a)
from the context (Validated a)
  bound by the type signature for
             makeValidated :: Validated a => Underlying a -> Maybe a
  at validated.hs:11:18-55
NB: `Underlying' is a type function, and may not be injective
The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
In the first argument of `validate', namely `u'
In the expression: validate u
In the expression:
  if validate u then Just (construct u) else Nothing
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Underlying` is a type function, which might not be injective. That is:

```
instance Validate T1 where
   type Underlying T1 = Int
   validate = ... -- code A

instance Validate T2 where
   type Underlying T2 = Int
   validate = ... -- code B
```

Consider now

```
validate (42 :: Int)
```

What should this do? Should it call code `A` or `B`? Since `Underlying T1 = Underlying T2 = Int`, it's impossible to tell.

It is impossible to call `validate` unambiguously. To avoid this, a possible fix is to add a "proxy" parameter to your validation function:

```
data Proxy a = Proxy

class Validate a where
    validate :: Proxy a -> Underlying a -> Bool
```

Now you can use:

```
validate Proxy (42 :: Int)               -- still ambiguous!
validate (Proxy :: Proxy T1) (42 :: Int) -- Now OK!
validate (Proxy :: Proxy T2) (42 :: Int) -- Now OK!
```

Comment: I tried modifying my code as follows, but I am getting the same error message. What am I doing wrong?

`data Proxy a = Proxy`  
``  
`class Validated a where`  
  `type Underlying a`  
  `validate :: Proxy a -> Underlying a -> Bool`  
  `construct :: Underlying a -> a`  
  `use :: a -> Underlying a`  
``  `makeValidated :: Validated a => Underlying a -> Maybe a`  
`makeValidated u = if validate (Proxy :: Proxy a) u`  
                    `then Just (construct u)`  
                    `else Nothing`

Comment: @NioBium You need to use `makeValidated :: forall a . Validated a => ...` and enable the `ScopedTypeVariables` language extension. Probably a better choice could be to remove `validate,construct` from your class and add `makeValidated` instead in the class.

Answer (score 4):

The `validate` function, as written, is not usable in current GHC. Looking at its type signature:

```
validate :: Validated a => Underlying a -> Bool
```

you might reasonably think that, given a value of type `Underlying a`, one can figure out which `Validated` instance to use, namely, the `a` one. But this is a mistake: since `Underlying` is not injective, there may be types `b` and `c` for which `Underlying b ~ Underlying c`; hence neither `b` nor `c` can be a canonical choice for which instance to use. That is, there *is* no good mapping `F` on types for which `F (Underlying a) ~ a` is always true!

An alternative would be to use a data family rather than a type family.

```
class Validated a where
    data Underlying a
    validate :: Underlying a -> Bool

instance Validated Name where
    data Underlying Name = Underlying String
    validate (Underlying name) = ...
```